# MongoDB aggregate assert: command failed

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I use this query to find status( "isActive": false) **true or false** also find age depending on status last count total amount

```
db.programmershelper.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "isActive": false
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "age",
        total: { $count: "$amount" } 
    }
}])
```

show this message as well
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unknown group operator '$count'",
    "code" : 15952,
    "codeName" : "Location15952"
}

following error

> aggregate failed
>   _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13

Comment: what is `age` here? and what is "amount"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [count, sum and average docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#calculate-count-sum-and-average) for `group` to find the exact solution per your requriements.

As to what I understood from the question , you want to aggregate based on filter `"isActive": false` and finding age depending on the last total count.

```
db.programmershelper.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "isActive": false
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "age",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}])
```